# Any wrong code at this, the data still entering to database

Tags: php

If the database has the same phone number with new registered user, the register progress not completed, but at my code, the data still enter the database table with same phone number.

```
<?php 

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $no_hp = $_POST['no_hp'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    require_once 'connect.php';

        $sql = "INSERT INTO user(name,no_hp,email,password)VALUES('$name','$no_hp','$email','$password')";

        $hpcheck = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE no_hp='$no_hp' LIMIT 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $hpcheck);

        if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){

            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
            {
                $result["success"] = "0";
                $result["message"] = "Nomor hp telah digunakan!";
                echo json_encode($result);
                mysqli_close($conn);
            }
            else
            {
                $result["success"] = "1";
                $result["message"] = "success";
                echo json_encode($result);
                mysqli_close($conn);
            }
    } else {
        $result["success"] = "0";
        $result["message"] = "errorss";

        echo json_encode($result);
        mysqli_close($conn);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: You create your INSERT query, create and run your SELECT query, then run your INSERT query. You can't select what you haven't inserted yet.

Comment: so what should i do @aynber ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to 'insert if not exists' in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are executing your insert query by:

```
mysqli_query($conn, $sql)
```

before checking if the phone number already in the database.

Try to change your code as below:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $no_hp = $_POST['no_hp'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    require_once 'connect.php';

        $hpcheck = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE no_hp='$no_hp' LIMIT 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $hpcheck);

        if($result){

            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
            {
                $result["success"] = "0";
                $result["message"] = "Nomor hp telah digunakan!";
                echo json_encode($result);
                mysqli_close($conn);
            }
            else
            {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO user(name,no_hp,email,password)VALUES('$name','$no_hp','$email','$password')";
                mysqli_query($conn, $sql)
                $result["success"] = "1";
                $result["message"] = "success";
                echo json_encode($result);
                mysqli_close($conn);
            }
    } else {
        $result["success"] = "0";
        $result["message"] = "errorss";

        echo json_encode($result);
        mysqli_close($conn);
    }
}
```

This will only insert value if it is not exist in the database.